# Which tokens can I use in a rule to email all suppliers mentioned in an entity reference field?

Tags: commerce, rules, tokens

In my website, I need to send a notification email to suppliers. I’ve created a content type supplier with email, warehouse 1 and warehouse 2 as fields.

In commerce product, I’ve created a supplier field (entity reference).
Now, I need to send an email on the rule event ‘completing the checkout process’ to those suppliers for them to start preparing the products for pickup and I can’t find any related tokens on the Rules Action ‘*Send email*’.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question is about D7, you could try to create a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) of those suppliers that you want to send an eMail to.

After you succeeded in creating such view, you can *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions (in the rule you already have in place related to your Rules Event about "*completing the checkout process*":

- load the VBO list of those suppliers.
- add a loop to perform a Rules Action "send an eMail", for each supplier contained in your Views results.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was swamped in the project, what I did so far, is generate suppliers emails in views, and used the views rule module to loop the supplier emails and send them the mails one by one. the weird thing is, in rules, the views loop is performing once, although i have several rows

Comment: @user3414580 I assume you mean the [Views rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module. If my assumption is correct, then I'm not surprised about your "performing once" problem. What I suggested in my answer here is different, and it does not use that "Views rules" module. Want to retry what I suggested in my answer? Only using "VBO" and "Rules"?

Comment: Yes i'll try it, once done, i'll get back here and update

Comment: Hi, i've tried your way exactly and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @ram_griever : merci for "accept" ... next question!?!?

Comment: haha, thanks, am doin' a huge customized e-commerce website, and there are so many hickups...am swamped once i hit a wall i'll share...cheers